# Passing String from C function to C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I have the following test function set up in a C project:

```
__declspec(dllexport) int test(char *str, int strlen){
    char* h = "Hello";
    int length = 5;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        str[0] = h[0];
    }
    return strlen;
}
```

And in my C# project I declare the method as follows:

```
 [DllImport("solver.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode ,CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 public static extern int test(StringBuilder sol, int len);
```

And I try to use it in my project like so:

```
StringBuilder sol = new StringBuilder(15);
int t = test(sol, sol.Capacity);
string str = sol.ToString();
```

I'd like to pass "Hello" back to the C# code as a test, but when I run the code the StringBuilder stays empty, and even though 15 is passed to the C function as the length, when the C function returns the length it returns a 'random' large number like 125822695. What am I missing?

Comment: You might be missing that `char` is MBCS, not Unicode. Try to  change that to `wchar_t`. But I think there is more missing. Have you tried doing it the other way around, i.e. creating a C++/CLR wrapper (managed C++) around your C library and use that instead of directly messing with `DllImport`?

Comment: You declare your method as `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode`, but it looks like it's using 8 bit chars to me. Secondly, `str[0] = h[0];`... Should that not be `str[i] = h[i];`? Actually, it looks like there may be other bugs in the C function. I would suggest you (unit) test it properly within the C environment, before trying to call it from C#.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten That's what I get for writing code early in the morning. I also tried CharSet.Ansi but neither seemed to work.

Comment: @ConorWatson Why would you write `Unicode` when you know that it is `Ansi`. Don't attempt to write code by trial and error.

Comment: @donmartin Would I not still have to use DllImport?

Comment: Not if you used C++/CLI, but why give up on p/invoke so easily. It's not a hard p/invoke to write. And in any case, switching to C++/CLI won't change the fact that your unmanaged code is broken.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree that it's not a hard P/Invoke to write, but still, depending on how large the interface is going to be, I would recommend doing the glue code in C++/CLR instead of hard-wiring it via `DllImport`. But that's just my experience with this. Admitted, C++/CLR also has its caveats.

Comment: @donmartin These days it is C++/CLI, FWIW. Complex interop is certainly easier with C++/CLI than with p/invoke. But it can very often be more convenient in terms of deployment to wrap things up with p/invoke. You might not want to introduce extra assemblies. Or you might want to supply C# library code rather than C++/CLI.

Comment: CLI, CLR,... :-) Managed C++. Yup, you're certainly right that it's leaner deployment-wise without the wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

A number of problems:

1. You state `CharSet.Unicode` in the C#, but use `ANSI` in the unmanaged code.
2. You only write to the first character.
3. You ignore the value of `strlen` passed to the function.
4. You don't attempt to write a null-terminator.

As for the value returned from the function, that cannot be explained by the code that you present. There is something missing from your question that we need to see in order to explain that.

It is quite common when we see these questions, that the unmanaged code is clearly broken. It's hard enough to write correct p/invokes to correct unmanaged code. Trying to debug the p/invoke and the unmanaged code at the same time is so much harder. Test your unmanaged code in an unmanaged setting first. Only when you are confident it is correct should you move to write your p/invoke.